# Python pip install error: ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

Tags: python, pip

I just upgraded pip to version 8, and now when I attempt to install packages I get this error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 119, in get_platform major, minor, micro = release.split('.')

ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

I tried downgrading pip, but I still receive the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this error as well. I believe it's due to a bug on line 119 of `pep425tags.py` which was located on my machine at `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py`. This seems to have solved it:

**Original:**

```
release, _, machine = platform.mac_ver()
major, minor, micro = release.split('.') # line 119
```

**Change to:**

```
release, _, machine = platform.mac_ver()
major, minor = release.split('.') # line 119
```

The code on line 119 is expecting to have 3 values returned to it by `split`ing on periods, but, on my machine at least, `platform.mac_ver()` returns `'10.11'`.

I have been able to successfully install, upgrade, and uninstall several packages after this change, so it seems as though everything else is working fine.

Comment: It looks like this is fixed in 8.0.2